# Determine element left of cursor in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible determine the character on the left of the cursor's current position?

Basically if the cursor is at, `x-45` I'd like to determine if it's prefixed by a `{` character.

Comment: I think you can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/263743/508702

Comment: Baszz, thank you I'll look into the link.